# Wix adding folder as component into installer

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.5

i trying to put vsto vsto project into wix installer whom contain 3 files (exe, vsto and folder with application files)

The problem is that i can't put folder into installer , then i put .exe and .vsto files as a component into wix installer all ok , but then i try to put folder , i get an error :

```
"The Component/@Id attribute's value, 'Application Files', is not a legal identifier.  Identifier's may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore. (CNDL0015)
```

Here is my full code of product.wxs:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="dddf18f9-28e4-445c-92a1-734e5e774125">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />      
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
  </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="setup.exe">
        <File Id="setup.exe" KeyPath="yes"
        Name="setup.exe" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Com.VistaDraft.Distribution.Mvp.vsto">
          <File Id="Com.VistaDraft.Distribution.Mvp.vsto" KeyPath="yes"
                Name="Com.VistaDraft.Distribution.Mvp.vsto" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Application Files">
          <File Id="Application Files" KeyPath="yes"
                Name="Application Files" Source="$(var.AddinFiles)"></File>
          </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Maybe whom plz help with adding a folder into wix installer ?

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix this yourself? The error message that is returned looks to be clear to me. Have you tried changing the Id attributes to see if they fix the problem? What result did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you referenced tells you that Id attributes can only have a-z, A-Z, digits, underscores, and periods. The Id attribute you have used has a space in it.

Comment: for a testing i delete space, now is: ApplicationFiles, but now i have error : The system cannot find a the file on "c:/.../ApplicationFiles" but the path is good , because my another 2 files on same path. i guess the problem is that i try to add folder , but do something wrong , maybe you know how can i add folder into installer properlly?